# Proguard causes Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.BaselineLayout

Tags: xamarin, proguard, shrink

so I wanted to test the r8/proguard shrinker in
vs 2019 xamarin.forms 4.1.0.5568
linking sdk only
multi-dex enabled

i get following error:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.BaselineLayout'
```

my proguard.cfg looks like this:

```
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

-keep class android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
-keep class android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }


-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
protected java.lang.Object[][] getContents();
}
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.*
```

if i disable code shrinking, the error disappears.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide code sample for us to test?

Answer (score 1):

i simply added this line to my proguard config

```
-keep class android.support.design.internal.**{ *; }
```

and it works like a charm